# C++: Getting some continuous errors in c++ code in declaration and implementation

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, console-application, clr

.H file

```
#include "stdafx.h"

namespace XNameSpace{

    class ClassName
    {
    public:
        UserId GetId(); // Error 'GetId' Unknown override specifier // syntax error : '(' , unexpected token preceding ';'
    };

    enum UserId
    {
        Universal = -1,

        None,
        //
        C4,
        //
        C5,
        //
        C1,
        //
        C2,
        //
        C3,
    };
}
```

.CPP file

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Header.h" 

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

namespace XNameSpace{

    UserId ClassName::GetId() // 'GetId' is not a member of ClassName
    {
        String^ strUserName = "sdfasd";
        String^ strPasscode = "sdfa";
        UserId ^ObjRole= AuthenticationManager::NewRole();

        Dictionary<String^, Object^>^ users= gcnew Dictionary<String^, Object^>();

        users->Add("UserName", strUserName);
        users->Add("Passcode", strPasscode);

        UserId Id = (UserId)ObjRole->GetId(users);

        return Id;
    };
}
```

Can you help me on these issue

I have put the errors in the comment section of the coding . please have a look

> Error C3646   'GetId': unknown override specifier
>   Error C2059   syntax error: '('
>   Error C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   Error C2039   'GetId': is not a member of 'XNamespace::ClassName'
>   Error C3646   'GetId': unknown override specifier
>   Error C2059   syntax error: '('
>   Error C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
>   Error C2039   'GetId': is not a member of 'XNamespace::ClassName'

Comment: As a member for almost three years, now is *really* the time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What I mean is that you need to *tell* us what errors you get. Copy them (as text), in full and complete, and paste it into the question verbatim without modifications. Also point out *where* the errors are, for example by adding comments in the code you show.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.... I have already put errors in the comment of that particular line as well dude...Additionally i have listed all the errors in the bottom...

Comment: By the way, you *do* know that symbols must be declared *before* they are used? Like when you use `UserId` in the `ClassName` class, that `UserId` symbol doesn't exist yet. Furthermore, if you don't `#include` the header file in the source file, the compiler will know nothing about the contents of the header file. Learn the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)).

Comment: Dude... header name is there.... Even i don't get any errors in referring class and functions. I am getting error while compiling. is this correct way to use header and implementation ???

Comment: Again, ***declaration order matter***. Symbols must be declared ***before*** they are used. Think about that in the context of the `UserId` and `ClassName::GetId` declarations.

Comment: Thanks dude.: Actually all errors gone after i declared the UserId declaration in before the class.,.. Getting new errors pasted below


1) Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: enum XNamespace::UserId __cdecl XNamespace::ClassName::GetId(void)" (?GetId@Class1@XNamespace@@QEAA?AW4UserId@2@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl abc::function(void)" (?function@abc@@QEAAXXZ) 


2) Warning LNK4075 ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:LBR' specification
3)Error LNK1120 1 unresolved externals

Comment: Is the CPP file part of the project? Maybe it isn't compiled at all?

Comment: Cpp file is a part of the project, While compiling the project and solution leads to the this error.